# Regression in R for data frame with only positive values

Tags: r, regression

I need to run a regression for a dataframe in which one variable (`like_count`) only has positive values. The following df is a simplified version of my data with the min. and max. values from my data:

```
like_count <- c(631827, 0, 0, 4012)
  
news_media <- c("ABC", "ABC", "NZZ", "CNN")

data <- data.frame(news_media, like_count)
```

How do I correctly calculate a regression for this data frame? I want to predict the `like_count`  depending on the `news_media` .

So far, I tried the following:

```
model <- lm(log(like_count) ~ news_media, data = data)

summary(model)
```

This leads to an error, because I receive -INF values with `log(like_count)`.

Does anybody have an idea what I can do to run a correct regression?

Comment: Maybe relevant https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/443447/linear-regression-adding-constant-to-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because when you used log function to `like_count`, 0 values return to -Inf.

First of all, create new variable with taking logarithm of `like_count`.

```
log_like_count = log(like_count)
```

then you can change -Inf values to 0's by using `ifelse` function from base R.

```
log_like_count = ifelse(log_like_count == "-Inf", 0, log_like_count)
```

After that, you can add a new variable to your data frame and run the model again without using the log function.

```
data$log_like_count = log_like_count  
model = lm(log_like_count ~news_media, data = data)  
summary(model)
```